# navigate up and down with keybaord within html menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

could some one please integrate my code with keyboard arrows to navigate the menu up and down with less code as possible. i've tried some plugins and searched alot but my little experience does not help me!

```
$(function() {
$('ul.nav a').each(function(i, elem) {
$(elem).bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var offset = i * 38;
    $('ul.nav').stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0 ' + offset + 'px'}, 2000,'easeOutQuart');

    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 2000,'easeOutQuart');
        $('ul.nav a').css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'color': '#643D21'});
        $anchor.css({'cursor': 'default', 'color': '#995D32'});
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
});
```

HTML code

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#what">what</a></li>
<li><a href="#who">who</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
```

appreciated,

Comment: Please provide a more complete code sample, ideally on http://jsfiddle.net/ . Your JavaScript, with that limited HTML snippet, doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @mblase75 here it is http://jsfiddle.net/MwMt3/ .
besides, when clicking an list item the whole body slides to a section on the page named as the anchor' id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Why don't I just give you the whole thing? http://jsfiddle.net/MwMt3/2

```
$(function() {
    var hgt = $('ul li:first').height();

    $('ul.nav a').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var offset = i * hgt;
            animate_bg(offset);

            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 800);
            $('ul.nav a').css({
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'color': '#643D21'
            });
            $anchor.css({
                'cursor': 'default',
                'color': '#995D32'
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var bgtop = parseInt($('ul.nav').css("backgroundPosition").split(" ")[1], 10);
        var sel = Math.ceil(bgtop / hgt);
        if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40) { // right, down
            if (sel < 0) {
                animate_bg(0);
            } else if (sel < $('ul.nav li').length - 1) {
                var offset = (sel + 1) * hgt;
                animate_bg(offset);
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38) { // left, up
            if (sel < 0) {
                var maxoffset = $('ul.nav li').length * hgt;
                animate_bg(maxoffset);
            } else if (sel > 0) {
                var offset = (sel - 1) * hgt;
                animate_bg(offset);
            }
        }
    });
});

function animate_bg(offset) {
    $('ul.nav').stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: '0 ' + offset + 'px'
    }, 800);
}
```

Comment: i had found this code alot but don't know how to make it work with my function.
thanks any way

Comment: @jon: Okay, updated with working code. Optimize at your own leisure.

Comment: works great with keyboard but not executing the rest of the function>> sliding the body to the targeted section on the page
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 800);

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could describe a bit more clearly what you mean by "navigate the menu up and down", but here's my interpretation: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/NknCW/2/

We essentially just bind the keydown event to the page and check if either of the keys pressed were the up or down arrow:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which === 38){ //up
            var currentLI = $('li.selected');
            var currentLIprev = currentLI.prev();
            if(currentLI.length > 0 && currentLIprev.length > 0){
                currentLI.removeClass('selected');
                currentLIprev.addClass('selected');
            }else{
                $('li:first').addClass('selected');
            }
        }else if(e.which === 40){ //down
            var currentLI = $('li.selected');
            var currentLInext = currentLI.next();
            if(currentLI.length > 0){
                if(currentLInext.length > 0){
                    currentLI.removeClass('selected');
                    currentLInext.addClass('selected');
                }
            }else{
                $('li:first').addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is just what i need , but i don't know how to integrate this function with my working one with the same effect.
some explanation for original code:
the effect is animating the ul' background image below the list items when the list clicked , and the BG shifts 38px for each item.
thats the point ,the effect applies on the ul not the list so "selected" class wont work for me .
thanks

Comment: @maxedison. open your demo and press ANY key.

Comment: @roXon - thanks. Was using assignment (=) rather than a comparison (===) in if(e.which === 40)

Comment: Jon -- could you provide an image mockup of what you want? It's not clear enough to me.